# Clicking Linkbutton in a gridview doesn't fire the codebehind

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, modalpopupextender, multiview

I have searched for a solution on this site and others and I have not been able to find my exact case so here goes...

I have a panel that is used as a modal popup by using the modal popup extender.  Inside of this panel is an update panel that contains a multiview control.  The views for the multiview contain grids.  Different grid for different views.  The left most field on the grid is a template field that contains a link button.  This **should** fire the code behind to redirect to another page.  Instead, it appears to reopen the popup with no data displayed.

So...here are the events as I perform them.

I click a button on the webpage that opens my popup that contains my grid.  The correct view displays containing the correct grid and my data is correct.  I click on my linkbutton that should direct me to a new page and instead I get the same popup with no data in the grid.

I have this exact functionality in use on another webpage, the only difference is that I don't use multiviews. However, I at least know that the linkbutton in the grid inside the update panel fires the code behind.

I have tried an image buttons it reacts the same.  The hyperlink field does work and can be used, but I want to see if I can get the linkbutton to work so that I have a little more flexibility.

Comment: Can't say much without seeing some of your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can add Click event on your LinkButton, you add this when you iterate on your Grid in RowCreated.

```
void GridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      LinkButton button= (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("IdButton");
      button.Click += YourDelegate; //Adjust here your called delegate
    }
  }
```

Nota : you must ensure that you don't rebind your Grid every time that you post datas

You can use

```
if( ! IsPostBack)
{
  //Bind your grid
}
```

You presist with ViewState

Comment: I believe that I tried this previously, but the following line. `LinkButton button= (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("IdButton");` came back as nothing

Comment: you replace with id of your link button, adjust this ("IdButton") with your id of linkbutton

Comment: Yeah, i know, i think that case was when it was directly in the page and it was looking for the $ct....name

Comment: This is what I have in the RowCreated event on the grid. `If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then Dim button As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("uAssignLinkButton"), LinkButton) AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf MyEvent End If` I placed a breakpoint on the MyEvent sub and it never gets hit

Comment: add this <asp:GridView OnRowCreated="GridView_RowCreated" />

Comment: k...I added OnRowCreated="MyGrid_RowCreated" to the html and the event still does not get hit.

Comment: you don't forget to bind your datas just one time with ! IsPostBack and persist your dats with ViewState (Add also runat="server" to yours controls)

Comment: Databind is getting hit one time and runat="server" is set on the controls. Here is the html for by template field on the grid `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=""> <ItemTemplate> <asp:LinkButton ID="uAssignLinkButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Number") %>' Text="Assign" ToolTip="Assign this" runat="server" /> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>`

Comment: In the one that I have that works that does not involve the Multiview, I use the OnClick of the LinkButton and the code fires like it is expected to...

Comment: Okay, I think it definitely has to do with the Multiviews.  The page that I pop a grid up from currently that works, does not have the multiview control on it.  The one that I am trying to use it on, does have the multiview control.  I just took my exact code that I am using on the multiview page that does not work and placed it on a page without multiviews and it worked and fired the code in the code behind.  I must have event handlers getting lost when these multiviews are in use.

Answer (score 0):

> lick on my linkbutton that should direct me to a new page and instead I get the same popup with no data in the grid.

By that I suppose you click a link inside your modal Popup multiview's current view to navigate to another view. You can skip this altogether & use ASP.NET AJAX toolkit's tab control instead. You can place each gridview inside a separate tab & remove your link buttons.

Comment: I should be redirected to a different page entirely.  However, the same popup just either reopens or refreshes only there is no data.  This only happens when I pop it up from a page that has multiviews on it.  Every other page I have tested on works as expected.

Comment: I can't understand your overall scenario. Can you post a screenshot or some of your code ?

Comment: I have posted some code above.  Pretty much I just have a page that has multiviews.  On that page there is a button that when clicked opens the popup.  All of that works as expected.  But when the linkbutton is clicked it should redirect to different page.  Instead the popup that is open either closes and reopens or refreshes with no data.  Like I said, this only happens when the popup is on a page that has the multiview control